# Migrating to Yarn 2, but Yarn commands "set" and "policies" not found

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I am trying to migrate a project to Yarn 2 like it describes on their website: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration

When I run `yarn set version berry` I get this error:

```
yarn run v1.7.0
error Command "set" not found.
```

This [github forum post](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/904) says "Make sure you're using Yarn 1.22 as your global binary, or use yarn policies set-version instead."
I tried typing `yarn policies set-version berry` then I get the same error:

```
yarn run v1.7.0
error Command "policies" not found.
```

I am using Windows 7
node -v shows 13.14.0
yarn -v shows 1.7.0

Answer (score 3):

you should be in version 1.22 of yarn to be able to perform the set command

what solve to me the issue

```
yarn policies set-version
yarn set version berry
```